# How to find data source for aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following configuration to create aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity" "example" {
  comment = "Some comment"
}
```

How do I find data source for OAI from a different configuration?
For examples I have cloudfront distribution and I need to set `cloudfront_access_identity_path`

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "s3_distribution" {
  origin {
    domain_name = "abcd"
    origin_id   = "foobar"

    s3_origin_config {
      origin_access_identity = "how do i get cloudfront_access_identity_path here?"
    }
  }
```

I cannot use `aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.example.cloudfront_access_identity_path` because its in the different configuration.

I can access the data if I know the `id` however the id can change in future

```
data "aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity" "example" {
  id = "EDFDVDB123BHDS7"
}
```

What are my options to dynamically query aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity data source?

Comment: Pass the ID as an input parameter.

Comment: But how do you get the ID dynamically?

Comment: Dynamically from where? A different state file?

Comment: Yes different state file.. Note that the OAI is already created from different  .tf file.

Comment: Is it part of the same setup? Meaning, both OAI and the data source are executed during same tf apply?

Comment: No..there are executed in different apply

Comment: Had the same problem looking up the aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity created in a different stack, solved below with Terraform 0.15+ and provider 4.12.0+

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a data source for [aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identities](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/cloudfront_origin_access_identities) now which will let you search by matching their comments.

So theoretically (actually just tested) you could use the results from this data lookup in the aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity data lookup as long as the OAI you are looking for has a unique comment.

```
data "aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identities" "identities" {
  comments = ["some unique comment"]
}

data "aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity" "oai" {
  id = one(data.aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identities.identities.ids)
}
```

It was introduced in [AWS Provider version 4.12.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/v4.54.0/CHANGELOG.md#4120-april-28-2022)

Answer (score 0):

If they are are managed by different state files, you can't directly reference between them. The exception is if the configuration with OAI is in a remote state, then you can use [terraform_remote_state](https://www.terraform.io/language/state/remote-state-data) to reference this state's outputs in your code with `aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity` data source.

Alternatively, you can develop your own [External Data Source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) which would get the OAI from your setup in your code with `aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity` data source.

But the most common way is simply to pass the OAI as input variable to your tf files. If you want to do it automatically, you have to develop some script or wrapper around your tf code that will pass OAI variable automatically.